# Freezing, disk i/o problems iMac

Tags: mac, hard-drive, osx-snow-leopard, freeze

I have a desktop iMac with Snow Leopard installed on it. Every few minutes, I get freezing and

"kernel disk0s2: I/O Error"

in my console. I did some research, and found that my hard drive (a WD I had for only a year) may be failing. I've had failed hard drives before, and this doesn't seem like a failure because the hard drive is working quietly (there's no clicking noise at all even during the freezes) and I get a verified SMART status in Disk Utility. Are there any alternative theories to the kernel disk0s2: I/O Error in console or is it definitely an impending hard drive failure? Could it be due to overheating? WD drives get really hot. Any theories?

Comment: Did you tried some tools like [_Drive genius_](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/drive_genius.php) ? They could help…